# How to define massive in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need to test mysql queries in Mysql client. Therefore i need to define array in mysql, but i can't find how? Could you help me please?
I define array from backend:

```
WHERE
  rates.id IN  (:array) //node or rates.id IN ($array) php
```

Comment: Is your actual question ["how to bind an array in a mysql query in php"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any language/library supporting parameterized queries that supports collections of any sort as parameters. If you can find no other way to do it, using [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set%20FIND_IN_SET) should allow similar behavior (though you'll have to turn your array into a single string parameter; and it is a string function, and function in general, so it will make the query slow.

Performance-wise you are better off just manually constructing your query with the list in it; but then you lose the benefits/security of parameterization.